# Approach to solve root problem containing integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to solve some problem of the kind

$$ \int_{\mathcal X} f(x) e^{-yF(x)} \left[ \frac{a - y}{1-\gamma} [(1 - F(x))(1 - y) - 1] - [1 + y(1 - F(x)]\right] dx = 0$$

for $y$. $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ are pdf and cdf of $x$, so they're both to be taken strictly positive for the domain $\mathcal X$. How can I (generally) attack problems of this kind? Is there a general approach (say, take the derivative for some reason?) or does one have to look at each case independently?

Finally, is there any hope of solving this analytically at all or do I have to get coding?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does this problem arise from? Also can $y$ be anything or is it in $[0,1]$?

Comment: Substituting $1-F(x)=t$, and hence $f(x)d(x)=-dt$, then simplifying the expression will easily yield the solution. There doesn't seem to be any shortcut, unless $f(x)$ is some nice density, e.g., exponential.